# Changed the name of django app.Now python manage.py shell cant see the models.

Tags: python, django, shell

This is what I did to change the name of my django app which has classes under models

I deleted the database and the migration folder. Then I ran the migration again and the tables were created ( mariadb). All works fine. Except when I run 
`python manage.py shell` which starts the interpretor alright. But when I try to `from main.models import Teacher` I get a `LookupError: No installed app with label 'models'` . Teacher being the class under models.py of the app main. Main is what I had renamed my earlier app 'foo' to

Comment: Have you added `main` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes I have. I can run the server fine and use the admin interface to add records into the tables.

Comment: @anikomei Did you change app name in apps.py file? You'll need to change related url mapping in global urls file in project folder.

Comment: @gitblame no i did not touch apps.py. What do I have to do there?

Comment: In apps.py rename Config class to `MainConfig` and set `name` member to "main".

Comment: I think the problems is my directory structure. src->mange.py, pass. src is the BASE_DIR and pass in the PROJECT_DIR. the app main is under pass. I think the problem lies in the way the app and project is laid out

Answer (score 0):

Use relative import `from .models import Teacher` instead if you are inside your app **main**.

Comment: It works from inside 'main'. Its when i run `python manage.py shell` and then do `from main.models import Teacher` that I have the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Editing the Answer. I misunderstood the question earlier**

Hey, if the server is running and site is working as expected (as you mentioned) and you are facing problems only in shell, you just have to close the shell and reopen it.

However, here it seems that you have not added **init**.py file in the new folder as it can not fing models.py. If that is not the case, please edit the question to show the list of installed apps and the entire stack trace.

Comment: OP changed the name of app, not project. manage.py is a project wide file. You don't need to change manage.py if you rename one of the apps.